# How do I connect XtraReport to windows form on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

How do I connect XtraReport to windows form on Visual Studio 2010(This also must use a XtraGrid for Report viewing)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Form
2. Add PrintBarManager
3. Create new XtraReport

and try to use this code in your Form

```
    public partial class YourForm : XtraForm
    {
        private YourXtraReport report;
        public YourForm(PrintDocument document )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            report = new PrintingDocumentReport(document);
        }


        private void PrintingFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printControl1.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;
            report.CreateDocument();
        }
    }
```